# TeX refuses to produce a split index

Tags: indexing, makeindex, splitidx

I need an index of terms and an index of symbols for my document, and it seems like `splitidx` is a good way to do this. But it doesn't seem to work in my document. I eventually realized the problem is not with my code: the following MWE (from [a competent person](http://mbork.pl/2015-07-25_Multiple_indices_in_a_LaTeX_document_with_splitidx)) also doesn't work on my computer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[split]{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex[Index of notions and theorems]{idx}
\newindex[Index of symbols]{isy}

\begin{document}
We will first define the notion of a~\emph{metric space}\sindex{space!metric}, 
which we will usually denote by $(X,d)$\sindex[isy]{Xd@$(X,d)$}.

\printindex*
\end{document}
```

When I run `LaTeX`, `MakeIndex`, `LaTeX` on my file, `splitidx_min.tex`, the files `splitidx_min.idx` and `splitidx_min-isy.idx` are created and appropriately populated, as best I can tell, but the resulting PDF contains only the notion index and not the symbol index. How could I go about fixing this? I am using TeXShop and MacTeX.

**UPDATE**: I realized there was no corresponding `splitidx_min-isy.ind` file, but I was able to create it manually running `makeindex splitidx_min-isy` through the command line. However, when I compile the document, it still does not include this other index. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `makeindex` on both `.idx` files

```
makeindex <filename>
makeindex <filename>-isy
```

where `<filename>` stands for the main file name.

If you don't use the `split` option, running just

```
splitindex <filename>
```

will produce both indices at the next run of LaTeX.

Comment: Hi egreg, I worked out before to run a separate `makeindex` to make the file `splitidx_min-isy.ind` and edited my question to say this; but LaTeX still only includes the one index. I omitted the `split` option, deleted all my auxiliary files, ran LaTeX, did `splitindex splitidx_min` in the command line (which generated all the `.idx`, `.ind`, and `.ilg` files at once, and recompiled with LaTeX, but now it is not including any index at all. So far the only way I have been able to get the symbol entries in is to use the `allintoone` option for `splitidx`, which however does only yield one index.

Comment: Never mind: I had taken the `*` out of the `printindex` command at the end. Putting it back someone made things work. Thank you!